# MySQL query with WHERE NOT EXISTS returning no rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables, one called course and another called course_tutor_link. I am trying to get a list of all the courses that a tutor is not subscribed to. This would be a simple left join  but because at the start I will have courses that have no tutors attached to them this seems to mess up the code, so far I have:

```
SELECT  c.course_id, c.course,
users_id
FROM course AS c
LEFT JOIN course_tutor_link AS ctl
USING (course_id)
GROUP BY course_id
```

This will give me all of the courses including the ones that the user is subscribed to  (about 11 rows), as soon as I try and do a filter with the users_id I automatically also lose all of the courses that have no tutor attached eg.

```
SELECT c.course_id, c.course 
FROM course AS c
JOIN course_tutor_link AS ctl
USING (course_id)
WHERE users_id !=9
```

It drops down to just the courses I have tutors subscribed to. looking through SO I noticed the use of sub-queries and not exist but I just can't get the correct syntax, all I get is no rows returned, the query I have is:

```
SELECT  c.course_id, c.course,
users_id
FROM course AS c
LEFT JOIN course_tutor_link AS ctl
USING (course_id)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT course_id FROM course_tutor_link WHERE users_id = 9)
```

I'm obviously doing something stupid but I don't know what

regards

Zen

Comment: Your second code sample seems to be **identical** to the first.

Comment: sorry got code blindness, updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT c.course_id, c.course
FROM course AS c
    LEFT JOIN course_tutor_link AS ctl 
        ON c.course_id=ctl.course_id AND ctl.user_id=9
WHERE ctl.course_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Doh! talk about a brain fart. It works perfectly thanks toph and as I understand it more efficient than the subquery method that I was asking for and you have given below?, I completely forgot about the obvious IS NULL and had tried course_is=NULL which doesn't work

Comment: My two answers are correct. The better one depends of your data.You should try both against filled tables and choose the faster one.

Answer (score 0):

or

```
SELECT course_id, course
FROM course
WHERE course_id NOT IN (SELECT course_id FROM course_tutor_link WHERE users_id=9)
```

Comment: I believe it will be better if in the future you add 2nd (3rd, etc.) solution(s) to the same answer (edit) instead of creating new ones.